# Generate a Java compatible Diffie-Hellman using Python

Tags: python, cryptography, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

I am trying to rewrite the following code in Python. The original code is written in Javascript using the [sjcl](https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/index.html) library.

```js
// Inputs
var serverPubX = "WIUBDotrk02Rk/apL11jQPbmX0quyaYz2EIkGUlVf7s=";
var serverPubY = "diZ2CbfSUy5Kr82OIfd4Ajusq2K+/kjGZ7ymcqVwn2k=";

// The code
var serverPubXBits = sjcl.codec.base64.toBits(serverPubX);
var serverPubYBits = sjcl.codec.base64.toBits(serverPubY);
var serverPubKeyPointBits = serverPubXBits.concat(serverPubYBits);

var serverPubKey = new sjcl.ecc.elGamal.publicKey(
    sjcl.ecc.curves.c256, serverPubKeyPointBits);

var clientKeys = sjcl.ecc.elGamal.generateKeys(256, 1);

// What I need:
var sharedKey = clientKeys.sec.dhJavaEc(serverPubKey);
```

My main problem is the `dhJavaEc` function. According to the sjcl documentation, it's a [Java compatible Diffie-Hellman function](https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/sjcl.ecc.elGamal.secretKey.html#dhJavaEc). But I couldn't find anything equivalent in the pycryptodome library.

I checked the `dhJavaEc` code this is what it does:

```js
// Looks like it converts the server key to Jacobian and then multiply it by client key
serverPubKey.J.toJac().mult(clientKeys.sec.I, serverPubKey.J).toAffine().x.toBits()

// serverPubKey.J is the X and Y keys concatenated:
sjcl.codec.base64.fromBits(serverPubKey.J.toBits())
"WIUBDotrk02Rk/apL11jQPbmX0quyaYz2EIkGUlVf7t2JnYJt9JTLkqvzY4h93gCO6yrYr7+SMZnvKZypXCfaQ=="

// In my example, clientKeys.sec.I is this:
sjcl.codec.base64.fromBits(clientKeys.sec.I.toBits())
"zIhDVlFUpWQiRP+bjyEIhSLq8rcB8+XInXGhm6JGcVI="

// And the calculated key is:
sjcl.codec.base64.fromBits(sharedKey)
"ZBin/RV1qnfKoIuel+5fzv1y8rn3UZkMPO3pXva3VzQ="
```

### How can I generate a "sharedKey" equivalent using Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*PyCryptodome* does not seem to support ECDH at the moment, see [*Future plans*](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/future.html). An alternative is the *Cryptography* library, see [*Elliptic Curve Key Exchange algorithm*](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.html#elliptic-curve-key-exchange-algorithm).

The library expects the private key as *int* and the public key in uncompressed format as *bytes object*. The uncompressed format consists of the concatenated x and y coordinates preceded by a 0x04 byte.

[`sjcl.ecc.curves.c256`](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/ecc.js#L363) defines *secp256r1* (aka *prime256v1* aka *NIST P-256*).

Then a possible implementation in Python with *Cryptography* is:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec
import base64

curve = ec.SECP256R1()

clientKey = 'zIhDVlFUpWQiRP+bjyEIhSLq8rcB8+XInXGhm6JGcVI='
privateKeyInt = int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(clientKey), byteorder='big', signed=False)
privateKey = ec.derive_private_key(privateKeyInt, curve, default_backend())

serverPubKey = 'WIUBDotrk02Rk/apL11jQPbmX0quyaYz2EIkGUlVf7t2JnYJt9JTLkqvzY4h93gCO6yrYr7+SMZnvKZypXCfaQ=='
publicKeyUncomp = b'\x04' + base64.b64decode(serverPubKey)
publicKey = ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(curve, publicKeyUncomp)

sharedSecret = privateKey.exchange(ec.ECDH(), publicKey)
print(base64.b64encode(sharedSecret).decode('utf8')) # ZBin/RV1qnfKoIuel+5fzv1y8rn3UZkMPO3pXva3VzQ=
```

which produces the same shared secret as the JavaScript code.